# Same echo command which has control characters showing different output

Tags: bash, echo, control-characters

If I run `echo -en "aap\0icon\x1f${icon}\n"` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array="Alacritty vscodium firefox-esr io.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch folder"

for icon in ${array}; do
    echo -en "aap\0icon\x1f${icon}\n"
    echo -en "aap\0icon\x1f${icon}\n" | head -1 | od -c
done
```

The output of the command is:

```
$ ./test
aapiconAlacritty
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037   A   l   a   c   r   i   t
0000020   t   y  \n
0000023
aapiconvscodium
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037   v   s   c   o   d   i   u
0000020   m  \n
0000022
aapiconfirefox-esr
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037   f   i   r   e   f   o   x
0000020   -   e   s   r  \n
0000025
aapiconio.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037   i   o   .   g   i   t   h
0000020   u   b   .   c   b   o   x   d   o   e   r   f   e   r   .   F
0000040   S   e   a   r   c   h  \n
0000047
aapiconfolder
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037   f   o   l   d   e   r  \n
0000020
```

However, If I run `echo -en "aap\0icon\x1f${icon}\n"` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json=$(dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/GnomeUtilsWorkspaces org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GnomeUtilsWorkspaces.GetWorkspaces)

workspace_names=$(echo $json | jq -c -r .workspace_names[])

for w in ${workspace_names}; do

all_normal_windows_of_nth_workspaces=$(echo $json | jq ".all_normal_windows_of_workspaces .$w" | jq -c '.[]' )

    for item in ${all_normal_windows_of_nth_workspaces}; do
        icon=$(dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/GnomeUtilsWindows org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GnomeUtilsWindows.GetIconFromWinID uint32:$item)
        echo -en "aap\0icon\x1f${icon}\n"
        echo -en "aap\0icon\x1f${icon}\n" | head -1 | od -c
    done
done
```

The output is like:

```
./test
aapicon   firefox-esr
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037               f   i   r   e
0000020   f   o   x   -   e   s   r  \n
0000030
aapicon   Alacritty
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037               A   l   a   c
0000020   r   i   t   t   y  \n
0000026
aapicon   firefox-esr
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037               f   i   r   e
0000020   f   o   x   -   e   s   r  \n
0000030
aapicon   firefox-esr
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037               f   i   r   e
0000020   f   o   x   -   e   s   r  \n
0000030
aapicon   vscodium
0000000   a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037               v   s   c   o
0000020   d   i   u   m  \n
0000025
```

As a result I am unable to render the icons in rofi using `./test | rofi -dmenu` or, `rofi -show gn -modi "gn:./test"`.

One sample for rofi script can be found in https://github.com/davatorium/rofi/blob/next/Examples/test_script_mode.sh

[Documentation](https://man.archlinux.org/man/rofi-script.5.en) also says that we need to render icon using `echo -en "aap\0icon\x1ffolder\n"`.

I do not understand control characters well. Why does it work differently here. How can I have same output as first example, in the second code?

**P.S.** This is not necessary but if you want to know what is this script and how does it work then please check https://github.com/davatorium/rofi/discussions/1871

Comment: @jhnc do you mean the first script (`for icon in ${array};`) does not give any output?

Comment: please update the question with the expected output; in the 2nd set of code it's not clear (to me) that `icon` contains the same exact data as in the 1st set of code's array

Comment: when I run the 1st set of code (in cygwin/bash, in Ubuntu/bash) the first line of output is `aapiconAlacritty`; when I pipe that through `| head -1 | od -c` I get `a   a   p  \0   i   c   o   n 037   A   l   a   c   r   i   t   t   y  \n`; not sure how you manage to get just `Alacritty` in your output (setting aside the fact that the 1st set of output has 4 lines of output instead of the expected 5, one item is duplciated, the ordering is not the same as in the array)

Comment: for second script add `declare -p icon` after `icon=$(...)` line and see what is shown. and you can do `echo -en "..." | od -c` to check that

Comment: I have updated the question with `head -1 | od -c` output.

Comment: with the latest update it looks like the 2nd set of code is deailing with some leading white space in the value assigned to the `icon` variable; so, just remove the leading white space? eg, `${icon##+( )}` or `${icon##+([[:space:]])}` ... in this case the `+` could be replaced with `*`

Comment: @markp-fuso yes sir i think you have hit the bull's eye here. Let me check the code. Too many tabs open. Getting back to you.

Comment: @markp-fuso your diagnosys is correct. Solved the problem with ` | xargs` like `icon=$(dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/GnomeUtilsWindows org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GnomeUtilsWindows.GetIconFromWinID uint32:$item | xargs)

Comment: Try this: `read -ra workspace_names < <(dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/GnomeUtilsWorkspaces org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GnomeUtilsWorkspaces.GetWorkspaces | jq -cr '.workspace_names[]' )`... Then `for w in "${workspace_names[@]}"; do`

Comment: @markp-fuso if you kindly give the answer in answer section, i can accept it.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail  all I did was mention the leading whitespace; I didn't mention `xargs` so .... if you're using `xargs` (to strip leading/trailing spaces, to squeeze multi-spaces into a single space) then I'd suggest you go ahead and write up an answer detailing what you've done to address your issue